# IIS Server Frontend Client with ExtJS could not request(Store.load) to Java Back-end Server Application

Tags: java, tomcat, iis, extjs, java-ee-6

I have problem, In my case i use ExtJS as Web Client Front-end framework and that front-end deployed in IIS server, i try to request using Ext.data.Store.load() to Back-end Application Server deployed in Apache Tomcat(Because my Back-end programming language is Java), and there no action when i execute Ext.data.Store.load(), 
why Ext.data.Store.load() not working in IIS Server, Whereas it worked fine when Front-end deployed in Apache Tomcat,,

There is something must i configure with IIS Server ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the store proxy to invoke the tomcat service specifying tomcats host:port/contextpath ?

By default store proxy will just use the context path. That's the reason the same codebase is working as expected when deployed in tomcat.